# Caliburn.Micro return result from child view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

So I have a ViewModel which contains logic to select a person from a list and if the person to be selected is not in the list a list item to open a new dialogue to create said person.

My problem is: How can I create the person in the child view model and get it in the parent. I searched (a lot) and found nothing satisfactory.
As far as I know there are at least three possibilities:
1. Use CMs EventAggregator to send messages to the Parent (and everyone else listening)
2. Use a property on the child VM and access this after the WindowManger has closed the Dialogue.
3. Implement IResult

I already did the first one, but this is (as said) not satisfactory. I don't want everyone to get the result, just because he listens to the EventAggregator. The second one is (in my view) not very MVVM like (or is it?), since i cannot control it if it is async.
As far I can tell from CMs doc, the third option is the preferred way. However I found no explanation how to adapt it to my solution.
I have to get user input and this is not possible in the `Execute(CoroutineExecutionContext context)` method.

Am I overlooking something or is the second method really the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

2nd method is perfectly ok I have some situations where and I need a response result to proceed and get it upon closure of the view associated with the viewmodel that I call in a different method call, it could be done with a  service specifically designed to grab results, if you are looking for S.O.C to avoid conflicts later. The 1st method is actually something I use for a few things, except I directly control what can see the message (new class object to watch for) and the only screens that can react to the message will do something.. 3rd is extremely powerful but I haven't ever actually got into the CoRoutines usage, it was the answer to async before async/await were available.  There are lot of IResult examples floating around

Comment: Coroutines are definitely a bit of an orphan solution due async / await being more powerful. 2 is probably the best approach.